# Show that if $n$ is a positive integer and $n|2^n-1$, then $n=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have very limited experience with proofs, and I'm having trouble getting started with this.

This far I've been trying to prove it using the division equation $a=bq+r$, to show that the remainder $r+1$ is never zero for $n>1$ for
$2^n=nq+(r+1)$. Trivial cases are just that, and the part I'm guessing I'm having trouble with is how to generalize that, to apply to any n (if this is even a good way go about this).

Comment: Yes, I accidentally left out some information, the title has been edited accordingly.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers.

Comment: $2^n - 1$ looks like a difference of powers to me.  This is a question about (non-)divisibility.  Can we factor such a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $n \neq 1$.

Let $p$ be the smallest prime which divides $n$. Write $n= p^k \cdot l$.

Now, you know that 
$$1 \equiv 2^n \equiv (2^l)^{p^k} \pmod p$$

Use the fact that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ to conclude that $ (2^l)^{p^k} \equiv 2^l \pmod{p}$.

This shows that 
$$2^l \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
You also know that 
$$2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

This gives that $2^{\gcd (l, p-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Now, if $\gcd(l, p-1) \neq 1$ it is divisible by a prime $q$. This prime divides $l$ hence $n$, and $q$ also divides $p-1$ and hence is smaller than $p$. But this contradicts that $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$.

We can therefore conclude that $\gcd (l, p-1)=1$.

Thus
$2^1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \Rightarrow p\mid 2-1=1$.

This is a contradiction.

Comment: Alright, $2^n$ is always an even number, so the smallest $p$ will always be 2, which yields $(l,p-1)=1$, but 2 is not congruent to 1 (mod p). Is that correct, or did I just confuse myself?

Comment: @Kaliber If $p|n$ and $n|2^n-1$ then $p|2^n-1$ and hence $p$ is odd. $p$ cannot be $2$. The point is that it is irrelevant what $p$ is, what are the two smallest divisors of $l$?

Comment: I'm starting to feel really stupid now. Okay, so if $p$ is odd, then $n$ is either odd or even, that would make the smallest divisors of $l$, $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @Kaliber $2$ cannot divide $l$ since $n$ is odd. Hint: $(l, p-1)$ cannot be divisible by any prime $q$ because in that case $q|l|n$ and $q \leq p-1$. Which is the only positive integer not divisible by any prime?

Comment: That would be $1$, if I've not lost it completely.

Comment: @Kaliber Exactly. Which means that $(p-1,l)=1$. Therefore $2^{gcd (l, p-1)}=2\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ which means that $p|2-1$.